# Selenium script Error showing during initialization of boot layer

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to selenium. Working on eclipse to run my first test case but getting following errors when running the code.

```
 Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
    java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0.jar
    Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in module
```

i have imported selenium-server-3.9.0, selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0 and  bsf-2.4.0 jar files in my project.

this is the code i am running on eclipse:

```
package Automation;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("guptasakshi34@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.className("RveJvd snByac")).click();
        String at = driver.getTitle();
        String et = "gmail";
        driver.close();
        if(at.equalsIgnoreCase(et))
        {
            System.out.println("Test Successful");

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Test Failue");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: requires more info.

Comment: I have added proper code information. can you please look into it and let me know the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible the problem is that you have imported BOTH the Selenium Server and the Standalone server.  You need to choose one or the other (I prefer the standalone server since Selenium server requires you to remember to do

```
webdriver-manager start
```

and related commands.  Standalone server can just be specified in your exports.config file and you never have to worry about it.